# Force inclusion of observations with missing data in lmer

Tags: r, missing-data, lme4

I want to fit a linear mixed-effects model using `lme4::lmer` without discarding observations with missing data. That is, I want `lmer` to go ahead and maximize the likelihood using all the data.

Am I correct in thinking that using `na.pass` produces this behavior? [This unanswered question](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/10afwwt9ja/r-using-na-action-na-pass-with-lmer-function) is making me wonder if this might be wrong.

Comment: Program your own solution that does ML on partial observations.... then sumbit the push request to `lme4` on github so the rest of us can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

`lmer`(like most model functions) can't deal with missing data. To illustrate that:

```
data(Orthodont,package="nlme")
Orthodont$nsex <- as.numeric(Orthodont$Sex=="Male")
Orthodont$nsexage <- with(Orthodont, nsex*age)
Orthodont[1, 2] <- NA

lmer(distance ~ age + (age|Subject) + (0+nsex|Subject) +
       (0 + nsexage|Subject), data=Orthodont, na.action = na.pass)
#Error in lme4::lFormula(formula = distance ~ age + (age | Subject) + (0 +  : 
#  NA in Z (random-effects model matrix): please use "na.action='na.omit'" or "na.action='na.exclude'"
```

If you don't want to discard observations with missing data, your only option is imputation. Check out packages like [mice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) or [Amelia](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/index.html).

Comment: It may be the case that `lmer` can't handle missing data, but it's not correct that imputation is the only option. Mixed models fit via ML or REML can indeed maximize the likelihood despite missing observations. They do not require a least-squares solutions. e.g.: http://www.amstat.org/sections/SRMS/webinarfiles/ModernMethodWebinarMay2012.pdf

Comment: OK, maybe @BenBolker will see this and show how it can be done with lme4 (if I'm wrong and it is possible with lme4). Your question is rather restrictive since you state you want to do it with lme4,

Comment: I'd be okay with another R solution.

Comment: @half-pass I think you're looking for a FIML (full information maximum likelihood) solution, which is a bit different than ML/REML from standard mixed models packages.  There was a recent discussion about this on the R mixed models list.  See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2016q3/025045.html).

Comment: @aosmith Is there a way to perform FIML using the lme4 package? Or any other R package would work for me as well.